# Can a Cloud Dataflow python transform function use third party libraries?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784191/can-i-use-third-party-libraries-with-cloud-dataflow) I saw a Dataflow transform function in Java can use third party libraries. I am wondering if a transform function in Python can do also use third party libraries?

I can imagine how it works in Java since there is a jar file. However, for python, will the SDK creates a Python package and run it in the worker?

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed. See [Managing Pipeline Dependencies (Python)](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dependencies-python)

Comment: Precision, dataflow is a runner of Apache Beam. So the question is more about Beam itself than dataflow.
The following link backu your answer: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/